# Choose WebCams Via getusermedia

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I am beginner with `getusermedia`, just got some codes from Google, and I'm able to work on those. But i have to show options on my webapp, from where a user can select WebCam from Primary (Laptop) or Secondary (Connected via USB).

Tried this, working for primary (Laptop WebCam), but when i am adding USB WebCam, it is auto select USB WebCam.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
video = document.getElementById("video"),
imagegrid = document.getElementById("imagegrid"),
videoObj = { "video": true },
errBack = function(error) {
console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
};
var video = document.querySelector("#video");
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}
function handleVideo(stream) {
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
function videoError(e) {
// do something
}
// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", function() {

draw(video, canvas, imagegrid);
});
```

Is it possible, i can show options for both webcams.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `navigator.getUserMedia()` will only give you the default camera (with the exception of Firefox which gives you an option of which camera to share with the web application)

To avoid this problem you should use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and then `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`.

**Example:**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices)
  .catch(errorCallback);
...
function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {

  ...

  for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
        'Microphone ' + (audioInputSelect.length + 1);
      audioInputSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audiooutput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Speaker ' +
        (audioOutputSelect.length + 1);
      audioOutputSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' +
        (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

  ...

}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
    var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
    console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
    console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
    stream.onended = function() {
      console.log('Stream ended');
    };
    window.stream = stream; // make variable available to console
    video.srcObject = stream;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // ...
  }
```

The above functions use `promises` and require a more complex approach than yours. So you need to do some reading in order to adaptate this method. Have a look at the link below for some examples:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices